# javascript repeat() display each result in a new line.

Tags: javascript, repeat

Hi I am working with js and when creating an automatic list I use 
`var str = "<li>...content...</li>";
str.repeat(prompt('How Many Items'))`

and it displays like this

```
<li>...content...</li><li>...content...</li><li>...content...</li><li>...content...</li><li>...content...</li>
```

and I would like to display it like this:

```
<li>...content...</li>
<li>...content...</li>
<li>...content...</li>
<li>...content...</li>
<li>...content...</li>
```

this is strictly in code view as it is a line of code that it is being generated once the number of times to repeat has been defined.

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem, as it is difficult to say what actual issue you are having and how you are trying to display the data.

Comment: It was just missing the \n that was posted below. But I will make sure to include a full example on my next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line break at the end.

Change this:

```
var str = "<li>...content...</li>";
```

To this:

```
var str = "<li>...content...</li>\n";
```